# How do I Install GTK+ 3.0?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How can I install GTK+ 3.0 and use that instead of GTK+ 2.24?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GTK3 is installed by default, please don't download and compile from the GTK website.

If you want to use GTK3 yourself, compile against that instead GTK2, or use PyGObject instead of PyGTK if you're using Python.

If you want all programs to use GTK3 instead of GTK2, it won't work, it's a job for the application developers to port their application.

Comment: The package name changed a bit, try this: dpkg -l libgtk-[0-9]* | grep ^i

Comment: Also note that GTK2 and GTK3 are parellel installable. So it's not that you are using one or the other, it's the applications that choose which version.

Comment: @Nick if you have questions about specific apps, it would be better to ask a new question.  We wouldn't want useful information to get lost in the comments. :)

Comment: Wasn't installed by default on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Used below answer.

Answer (score 278):

To **use** gtk2 or gtk3 apps you don't need to install anything. But, if you want to develop (or even just compile) apps this is what you're looking for:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Comment: Is this true for Windows and MacOS as well (or just for Ubuntu or GNU/Linux?)

Comment: Just for Ubuntu.

Comment: this should be the preferred answer

Answer (score 3):

If you already have an older version of GTK and you want to upgrade it then you can do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```