# ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available

Tags: python

When following the instructions [2. Getting Started — Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial 3.4 documentation](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)

Tries

```
In [6]: import gi
   ...: gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
   ...: from gi.repository import Gtk
```

it report errors:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py in require_version(namespace, version)
    128     available_versions = repository.enumerate_versions(namespace)
    129     if not available_versions:
--> 130         raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
    131
    132     if version not in available_versions:

ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

Follow [How do I Install GTK+ 3.0? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101306/how-do-i-install-gtk-3-0) and intstalled Gtk to ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

However, it still report the same errors.

How could solve the problem?

Comment: You have installed another version of python3 and masked system python3. Execute `which python3` to know which python3 you used. System python3, which contains `gi` and `Gtk`, is located in `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: yes, after set /usr/bin/python3 as default it report the same error. @PingChuHung

Comment: Please update the error message. And append the outputs of `dpkg -l | grep libgtk3` and `dpkg -l | grep libgtk-3`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but solved it by just making a python virtual environment and then running the command you listed.